# Stop all MediaPlayer objects from a separate activity

Tags: android, timer, android-mediaplayer

I have `MediaPlayer` sounds that get started when a timer finishes. There are 5 different ones, all on 5 different activities, so none will play simultaneously. However, I noticed that when the timer is not finished yet, and the user leaves the activity (or presses the back button on their device), then the counter still counts down (which is good, that is wanted), but then when the timer finishes, the sound plays and there is no way to stop it.

So I created a Stop button on the main activity page (where none of the sounds actually play from, they all start in their own activity). But if a user leaves the activity to use some other app entirely, they should be able to come back to the app main page, and press the stop button to stop the sound that plays once the timer is done. But how do I do this?

I tried the code below, using an `onClickListener`, but I tried accessing the IDs of multiple sounds at once, so that I could call `onStop()` on them all in case one of them is playing at any given time, but my app crashed. Below is the LogCat. Thanks for your help.

P.S. I cannot use SoundPool (as some suggest) because my sounds are larger files than that class permits).

**Stop button listener on main activity page, in `onCreate()`:**

```
 btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainSelectorActivity.this,
                        R.raw.godzilla_roar|R.raw.nuclear_explode|R.raw.tsunami_wave_fx
                                |R.raw.volcano_exploding|R.raw.zombie_sound);
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
```

**LogCat after I press the stop button (while one of the sounds is playing):**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050007
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1013)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:975)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:824)
            at com.azurespot.disastertimer.app.MainSelectorActivity$2.onClick(MainSelectorActivity.java:57)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 04:50:46.207    3437-3437/com.azurespot.disastertimer.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Your stop button is creating an instance of media player on every touch. Try add there this condition: if (mp.isPlaying()) mp.pause().

Comment: Okay, do you mean I should take all those instances out? I tried to just use a generic MediaPlayer instance (one that does not reference any of my raw sound files) and it did not work, so I figured I had to access the actual sound files some how.

Comment: Every time you press the Stop button, you create a new instance of mediaplayer. This is bad. Declare your mediaplayer instance in the class (I don't know how to say it in English, I hope you understand) and make the button like this: if (mp.isPlaying) { mp.pause()} else { mp.play()}. I've also noticed that you don't use Uri.parse(content). Google it, use it.